# MySql query : Show Columns as Rows from 1 table

Tags: mysql, database, join, self-join

**Tables**: Employee and Project

**Employee**:

```
EmployeeID|  Username | 
----------+-----------+
1         | Manager1  | 
2         | Manager2  | 
3         | Employee3 | 
4         | Employee4 | 
5         | Employee5 |
```

**Project:**

**Note:** Columns **Project_ManagerID** and **EmployeeID** comes from 1 table (**Employee**)

```
 ProjectID | Project_Name| Project_ManagerID | EmployeeID
-----------+-------------+-------------------+---------
1          | Project 1   | 1                 | 3
2          | Project 2   | 1                 | 4
```

**Project table Explanation:**
For every Project, there are 2 Employee involve. Project Manager and a Regular Employee

*The query results I'm looking for:*

```
ProjectID  | EmployeeID | Username  |
-----------+------------+-----------+
1          | 1          | Manager1  |
1          | 3          | Employee3 |
2          | 1          | Manager1  |
2          | 4          | Employee4 |
```

I tried to make a self join but I'm getting difficulties in **showing 2 columns in Employee table to display a single Column as Rows** like my query result.

I always ended up 2 rows.. it should have 2 employee rows for every project.

```
2 Projects * 2 Employees = 4 Rows in total
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do `union all` something as

```
select
p.ProjectID,e.EmployeeID,e.Username 
from Project p 
join Employee e on e.EmployeeID = p.Project_ManagerID

union all

select
p.ProjectID,e.EmployeeID,e.Username 
from Project p 
join Employee e on e.EmployeeID = p.EmployeeID
```